# Discovering embedded management tools

Tags: powershell, ilo, embedded

I have a list of 130 IP addresses that I need to find out if they are ilo or another remote management tool. Is there a way to script this. Can I use the test-netconnection command in powershell.

Comment: "Is there a way to script this." I'm sure there is.  "Can I use the test-netconnection command in powershell."  You could, but I'd probably use [nmap's OS detection](https://nmap.org/book/osdetect-usage.html) first to see if that works.

Comment: https://github.com/urbanadventurer/WhatWeb/blob/master/plugins/ilo.rb

Answer (score 0):

Hit `https://iloaddress/xmldata?item=all` or `https://iloaddress/redfish/v1` or `https://iloaddress/rest/v1`

One or more of these should answer for every iLO IP.  The `xmldata` is the oldest and most generic.  The other interfaces were added in later generations.

You will likely want to parse the data returned to determine what management engine (ie iLO) is running it.  Also the response headers are very informative since you can glean what web-kit is on the FW to fingerprint it.